# Powershell command to Python

Tags: python, powershell

Trying to get the below code to run but am struggling to find a solution for the below highlight portion it doesn't like the 'File' portion of the code. Any help appreciated.

```
import subprocess    
def getaclsec():
    pscommand = '$file1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\\Source\\testpath.csv" ForEach ($file in $file1) {$infoSec = Get-Acl -Path $file.FullPAth $infoSec.Access | Select @{l='File';e={$file.FullPath}},* | Export-Csv -Path "C:\\Source\\newTestPathSect.csv" -Append}'
    process=subprocess.Popen(["powershell","& {" + pscommand + "}"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
getaclsec()
```

Comment: why didn't you use `""` around `File` like you used in other places.

Comment: Tried that but doesn't seem to be writing to a file still. This is a powershell command that im trying to run in Python, so thats how it is configured in PS without the ""

Comment: Your `pscommand` is being read as 1 entire line. Place a semicolon after your `Import-Csv` command as a "*statement terminator*" letting PowerShell know it's not part of the same line. `$file1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\\Source\\testpath.csv"; foreach (...`.

Comment: looks like you can escape a `'` with `''` so it would be `... Select @{l=''File'';e=...`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala didn't seem to make a difference still complains about 'File'

Comment: Can you run this in PowerShell without receiving the same errors?

Comment: Yes in Powershell its a little different though
`$file1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Source\TestPath.csv"
ForEach ($file in $file1) {
   $infoSec = Get-Acl -Path $file.FullPAth 
   $infoSec.Access | Select @{l='File';e={$file.FullPath}},* | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Source\newTestPathSec.csv" -Append
   }`

I have another PS command running in Python that runs in one line as well

Comment: ahhh, I see. You need a `;` after `Get-Acl` as well. Like this `$file1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Source\TestPath.csv" ;ForEach ($file in $file1) { $infoSec = Get-Acl -Path $file.FullPAth ;$infoSec.Access | Select @{l='File';e={$file.FullPath}},* | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Source\newTestPathSec.csv" -Append }`.

Comment: Yep I noticed that too when running from PS as a oneliner! But in Python it doesnt like @{l=`'File'`;e= not sure why

Comment: @Calarian did you try escaping the `'File'` single quotes with `''File''`? I think that is still part of the issue.

Comment: @frankM_DN yeah actually the answer is a mix between both you and Abraham, i need the semi colols and `"File"` good catch

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
import subprocess    
def getaclsec():
    pscommand = '$file1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\\Source\\testpath.csv"; ForEach ($file in $file1) {$infoSec = Get-Acl -Path $file.FullPAth; $infoSec.Access | Select @{l="File";e={$file.FullPath}},* | Export-Csv -Path "C:\\Source\\newTestPathSect.csv" -Append}'
    process=subprocess.Popen(["powershell","& {" + pscommand + "}"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
getaclsec()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).